# CSS multiple Image positioning and styling

Tags: html, css

[image: BBC main image]

I am making the BBC News website using only `HTML` and `CSS` and I have completed the top menu bar but after that there is a problem.

As you can see in the image there is one big image align to left and perfectly behind the text heading and there is 4 images that is need to be aligned at the right side of big image, 4 images are having same height and width which is 307 X 107 and there is text written on them as well.

Please anyone can help to achieve this layout i am tired of trying all things making `divs` and putting in to the list items and float left also nothing worked.

Comment: Put your html and css codes whatever you have done...

Comment: it's a mess and long

Comment: its saying too long where should i put the code.??

Comment: create a fiddle of it or codepen

Comment: i am sorry Taniya i don't know what you have just said  i never used these software...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/user/login/ you can sign up here and add your codes over there.

Comment: i have signed up pasted the code there css as well now what to do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/awais256/upz0c5nf/

Comment: here it is [https://jsfiddle.net/awais256/upz0c5nf/#]

Answer (score 1):

Awais, if you inspect the BBC site with developer tools, you can see exactly how they did it. They have one container and a UL class with 5 images. The large image takes up 50% of the div and and rest of the smaller images take 25%. All the content then floats left, and accounts for 100% of the div width.

Here is a quick snippet of what I did: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQgpwy

```css
.container {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#image1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#image2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

#image3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}

#image4 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#image5 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="image1"></li>
    <li id="image2"></li>
    <li id="image3"></li>
    <li id="image4"></li>
    <li id="image5"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want to look with inspect element becuase i am doing on my own and also i have looked as well as you have told me

Comment: Thats looks awesome Thanks Stas Christiansen

Answer (score 0):

Though the html structure and images are not showing properly in your fiddle I have tried some fixes over there. Try it, hope it will help you to go further.

HTML:

I have added the div 'gallery1' within div 'gallery'.

```
<div id="gallery">
   <ul id="bigimg">
      <li><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="gallery1">

      <ul id="smallimages">

        <li><img src="images/2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/5.jpg"></li>

      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

I have modified this part of your css

```
 #headingdiv ul{
      display: inline-block;
 }

 #bigimg{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}

#bigimg img{
     width: 100%; 
}

#gallery1 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 48%;
}

#smallimages li {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   /* width: 100%; */
   /* left: 620px; */
   /* top: -364px; */
   /* margin: 1%; */
   text-align: right;
}
```